# My .FBX model is not picking the .TGA texture file

Tags: unity, 3d, fbx

I'm at a complete loss.

An artist has sent me a 3D model so I can test it in Unity. This is exactly what I got:

```
 - Guy.fbx
 - Guy_DIF_512.tga
```

Alright. So I move the folder into the Unity inspector. Suddenly, a `Materials` folder is created within such folder. The `Materials` folder has one material.

Anyway, now I put the `Guy` prefab into the scene. It doesn't have textures applied.

No problem. A simple Google search yields this response:

> The textures for your model have to be in your Unity project for Unity
>   to apply them automatically when you import.
>
> There are 3 different ways to make sure this happens
>
> 1 Use Textures for your 3D model from a \textures directory already in
>   your Unity project
>
> 2 Embed them in the FBX
>
> 3 Copy the textures into your project before you import your model

I will avoid the second option for now to avoid troubling the artist. Let's see the third option...

> 3 If you are using 3D software packages that might not have newer FBX
>   plugins or are importing native files you generally do not have the
>   option to embed media, so you will need to copy the textures into a
>   directory inside your project called textures - nested next to the
>   model before you import it e.g.
>
> \Projectx\Assets\Models\Textures\ModelTexture.tga
>
> \Projectx\Assets\Models\Model.fbx

Ok, so I created `Assets/Models/Textures` and imported the `Guy_DIF_512.tga` file into it. Then in `Assets/Models` folder I import the `Guy.fbx` file.

Doesn't work. The model still doesn't have textures applied.

Alright, so let's look at the first option then.

... Let's look at the first option...

> 1 If you create your textures in your Unity project to start with and
>   source them from a \textures directory nested under Models for
>   example, Unity should always create materials and pick up the textures
>   correctly at import
>
> **\Assets\Models\Textures**
>
> **\Assets\Models**

Uh, isn't this the same as the third option?

**How do I import my 3D model?**

I am using Unity 5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know about Unity 5, but in 4, you can click on your model in the Scene window. On the Mesh Renderer properties, there should be at least one material.

To start, set the shader to "Diffuse", and click on "select" to select the texture. The character should appear textured.

If you want to save these settings for future use, drag the object from the Hierarchy panel to some folder in your Project panel to create a prefab for that precise model with that precise texture.

Comment: Really strange how this is not by default. Thanks.

Comment: It should work by default, but there are many reasons why the importer was unable to resolve the texture reference when loading it. It really depends on how the FBX file was exported, which depends on the modeling software used and the exporter settings. So instead of arguing with your 3D designer, you can just fix the reference when you load the file as I explained.